# Is it possible to do only a part of make-instances real?

Tags: instances

[image]

instancing is a very good function to reduce memory. But there is a limit to making it.
It's hard to change some directions.
The right side is made of alt + D.
Can I change the direction like on the right? Can I change some parts to real?

Comment: AFAIK it is not possible. Maybe you can use geometry nodes? Depends on what you want...you did not really describe what your goal is.

Comment: oh it is sad. thank you reply